# Excel 2010 countif function

Tags: excel, countif

I have the answers of a questionnaire and I need to translate the data.
Some questions had multiple choice answers.

They appear like, for example:

- ”apple, cherry, banana, melon”
- ”berry, apple, melon”
- ...

I need to count every answer separately.
How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

The Countif function can have 2 arguments. The first is the range to search, the second is what to look for. Specifically, you can check this link, it is very well explained: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-that-contain-specific-text

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*melon*")
```

To know how many answers contain "melon" in range A1 to A10.

Comment: .....but using that approach you need to take care if some answers might be sub-strings of others, e.g. this formula will also count cells that contain "Watermelon"!

Comment: That's very true, I did not think of that! To counter this, assuming the number of possible answers is finite, you can wrtie something like =COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*melon*") -  COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*watermelon*")